# Tool for mass adding properties to many xml files?

Tags: windows-7, xml

I have some xml that looks like this in each  report:

```
Header
Cell
/Cell
Cell
/Cell
...
/Header
```

In each cell I need to add:

```
                <property name="borderBottomColor">#E1E1E1</property>
                <property name="borderBottomStyle">solid</property>
                <property name="borderBottomWidth">thin</property>
```

This will take me about a week to do manually.

Is there a tool that could do this?

Thanks

Comment: What about using your favourite editor (vim, emacs, …) and a custom macro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/docs.php) - an open source, command-line XML editor.

It allows you for example to add or update nodes in an XML document. Which nodes are updated can be specified by an [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp) expression.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give an exact answer without actual sample XML input (and a full output example), but you could use XSLT

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Cell">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>           
            <property name="borderBottomColor">#E1E1E1</property>
            <property name="borderBottomStyle">solid</property>
            <property name="borderBottomWidth">thin</property>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You could run this with [Xalan](http://xalan.apache.org/) or [Saxon](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/) from the command line.